# Node.js как вернуть mysql2/promise

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, promise

Как можно получить rows из функции? возвращает только Promise {  }
Во всех примерах просто в консоль выводят...

```
 async function main() {  
 
    const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');  
 
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({ host: 'localhost', user: 'root', password: 'root', database: 'main' });  
 
    const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = ?', [1]);  
 
    return rows;  
 
}   

console.log(main());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не дожидаетесь разрешения промиса.

```
async function main() {  
    const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');  
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({ host: 'localhost', user: 'root', password: 'root', database: 'main' });  
    const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `ID` = ?', [1]);  
    return rows;  
}   

// Вариант 1 - 
main().then((res) {
    console.log(res)
});

// Вариант 2

async function waiter() {
    const res = await main();
    console.log(res)
}

waiter();
// Можно вот так
async function waiter2() {
    await main().then((res) -> {
        // Успешный ответ
        console.log(res)
    }).catch((e) => {
        // Ошибка
    });
}

waiter2();
```

В первом варианте код побежит дальше, а когда main вернет результат, то начнется выполнение кода из .then

Во втором случае, выполнение функции остановится на await и продолжится, когда вернется результат

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Принимаете ответ, нажмите пожалуйста на галочку, слева от ответа